# Creation 2D array for Mine game

Tags: minesweeper

Hello

I am trying to create emulation of "Mine game"

suppose we have matrix

0   0   0   0 

0    0   -1    0 

0    0    0   -1  

0   -1    0   -1

now each cell that not equal -1 should be represent numbers of mines

here code 
   for(int i=0;i

```
for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
 if(box[i][j]!=-1)
  {
  switch (i)
 {
 case 0: 
 iLEFT=0;
 iRIGHT=1;break;
 case 3:
 iRIGHT=0;
 iLEFT=1;
 break;
 case 1:
 iLEFT=1;
 iRIGHT=1;
 break;
 case 2:
 iLEFT=1;
 iRIGHT=1;
 break;
 default:
  iLEFT=1;
 iRIGHT=1; 
   break;
}



switch (j)
  {
case 0:
   jLEFT=0;`
   jRIGHT=1;
   break;
case 3:
   jRIGHT=0;
   jLEFT=1;
   break;
   case 1:
   jLEFT=1;
   jRIGHT=1;
    break;
    case 2:
    jLEFT=1;
    jRIGHT=1;
    break;
    default:
    jLEFT=1;
    jRIGHT=1;
     break;
  } 

// checking neighbor 
     if(box[i][j+jRIGHT]==-1)
         count+=1;
            if(box[i][j-jLEFT]==-1)
         count+=1;              
                    if(box[i+iRIGHT][j]==-1)
                 count+=1;
            if (box[i-iLEFT][j]==-1)
              count+=1; 
                if(box[i-iLEFT][j-jLEFT]==-1)
                {
                    if(i-iLEFT!=i) // trying to avoid double checking
                     count+=1;
                }
                if(box[i+iRIGHT][j-jLEFT]==-1)
                {
                    if(i+iRIGHT!=i)  //trying to avoid double checking
                     count+=1;
                }
                if (box[i-iLEFT][j+jRIGHT]==-1)
                {
                    if(i!=iLEFT) //trying to avoid double checking
                      count+=1;
                }

                if (box[i+iRIGHT][j+jRIGHT]==-1)
                {

                    if(i!=iRIGHT) //trying to avoid double checking
                      count+=1;
                }

                   box[i][j]=count;
                   count=0;
        }
```

My algorithm 

 iLEFT present row step left.

 iRIGHT present row step right.

 jLEFT and JRIGHT same for column 

 Suppose i=0 so we can step only one step right(down) 
 
 if i=1 we can step up and done ..same for j

"Case statement " update iLEFT/iRIGTH and jLEFT/jRIGHT for for enable side steps

 now "if" statement checking left/right up/done 2 diagonals for box[i][j](only one step always)

count counting performance of -1 values neighbor for box[i][j]

**you can see I still have double checking for same cells**

0   1   1   1 
 
  0   1   -1   2 
 
  1   2   4   -1 
 
  ***2***   -1   ***4***   -1

Answer (score 2):

You should also outline your algorithm along with the code to give out a better idea of how you are approaching the problem. It's really difficult to understand this code without an accompanying algorithm.

You could outline your algorithm in plain english, doesn't have to be pseudocode. It will help you understand the problem and solution better. For instance, something like this:

1. look at each mine
2. increment all it's non-mine neighbors

I think you are over-complicating the way you check for boundary conditions. Let's assume if the minefield was infinitely large in each direction. If we then picked any random `cell(i,j)`, it's **8** neighbours would be at:

```
cell(i-1, j-1) // top-left
cell(i-1, j)   // top
cell(i-1, j+1) // top-right
cell(i, j-1)   // left
cell(i, j+1)   // right
cell(i+1, j-1) // bottom-left
cell(i+1, j)   // bottom
cell(i+1, j+1) // bottom-right
```

Back to the actual finite-length case now. I'd suggest that instead of pre-calculating whether a cell is within bounds, you should always check all 8 neighbors, and discard the invalid ones.

A function that checks if a cell is valid is easy to write:

```
bool is_cell_valid(int x, int y, int rows, int cols) {
    if(x < 0 || x >= cols) {
        return false;
    }
    if(y < 0 || y >= rows) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I understand you algorithm now finally :)

1. look at each non-mine cell
2. change its value to the number of
   neighboring mines

The double checking is happening because you are not checking for all variables that are changing. For example, in this condition you are using iLEFT and jLEFT to go to the top-left cell. Since both variables are being used, you have to make sure that both of them are non-zero.

```
if(box[i-iLEFT][j-jLEFT]==-1)
{
    if(i-iLEFT!=i) // trying to avoid double checking
        count+=1;
}
```

The above should instead be

```
if(iLEFT != 0 && jLEFT != 0)
{
    if(box[i-iLEFT][j-jLEFT]==-1)
        count+=1;
}
```

**And this check should be applied on each of the 8 cells, not just the diagonal cells.**

---

Here's a tiny alternative to go through all 8 cells that are adjacent to some cell at (x, y) without using an if for each neighbor.

```
for(int i = -1; i < = 1; i++) {
    for(int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
        if(i == 0 && j == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        if(is_cell_valid(x + i, y + j, N, N);
            // cell is adjacent and within boundaries
            // do whatever calculations are needed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok I understand your algorithm now, it's simple.. but the program is very complex.

Comment: Hi,thank you for help, actualy i was change my algorithm :)
For example if my board 4X4 i am used board 6X6.
It is help me to avoid boundaries checking, because i am working only with internal board 4X4.

Comment: yeah, its better to make the algorithm flexible to handle any nxn board. that also makes you think about a general approach for solving the problem and the resulting solution is better in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

i second on including the illustration of your algorithm which will be alot easier to read
any way i have made a [minesweeper](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ldmhhkobonimkpkfoabdmmngbbjcgilo) game before and this could be the outline of the generate function

1. we will start with empty grid (full
   of zeros)
2. insert each bomb randomly in empty
   place (doesn't already have a bomb)
3. increment all the non-bombs
   neighbors

**additional feature**
delay the generation of the bombs after the first click so you can make sure not to place a bomb on the first cell the user clicks

and here is a code snippet

```
var i = 0
while (i < bombsNum){
    //generate a random location for the bomb
    var col=Math.floor(Math.random()*cols);
    var row=Math.floor(Math.random()*rows);

    //if new location is already a bomb
    if (cellsData[row][col] == -1) continue;

    //if new location is near the start region    
    if (col == startCol-1 || col == startCol || col == startCol +1){
        if (row == startRow -1 || row == startRow || row == startRow+1)
            continue;
    }

    i++;
    cellsData[row][col] = -1;
    //increment all the neighbors cells and make sure to handle the special cases cells (cells at the corner)
}
```